# Getting invalid token to Bison parser from yylex

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I have made lex/bison parser where I am using lex named token rules like:
a    {return Tok_A;}  and yacc has declaration of this token:
%token Tok_A   then grammar follows.
Everything works fine, if the string is right, it accepts.
Now I try to make more general parser using directly the alphabet in lex.
For some reason yacc gives me invalid token when I want to send "a" character:

```
//parser.l
%{
#include "parser4.tab.h"
%}

%%
[a-h]    {return *yytext;}
\n   {return 0;}  /* EOF */
%%

//parser.y
%{
   extern void yyerror(char *);
   extern int yylex(void);
   #define YYDEBUG 1 
 %}
 
%token a 

%%
S : a {printf("S->a");}
%%

int main(void)
{
#if YYDEBUG
  yydebug = 1;
#endif
    if(!yyparse())
        printf("End of input reached\n");
    return 0;
}

void yyerror (char *s)
{
  /* fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s); */
  printf("Incorrect derivation!\n");
}
```

When I compile, start and give program input a, its output is:

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Stack now 0
Reading a token
a
Next token is token "invalid token" ()
Incorrect derivation!
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token "invalid token" ()
Stack now 0
```

I think the trick is in lex and the rule return *yytext.*
If I understand it right, yacc and lex communicate through parser.tab.h. There are definitions for token translation int to token name. From int 257. 0-255 are used for classic characters.
So should I somehow translate the token in lex to ASCII? I thought when lex sends directly the "a" char, bison/yacc would understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `%token a` it defines `a` as a name for a token, which you could return from lex.  But that is not the same as the character `'a'`.  If you want to use the character `'a'` as a token in the grammar, you DON'T need to declare it, but you DO need single-quotes around it, as `'a'` and not `a`

In your case, change the yacc grammar to

```
S : 'a' {printf("S->a");}
```

and it will work

Comment: Thanks. I have searched the error for hours, tenths of hours.